# Lambda function que interactua con AWS docker container

Tags: docker, aws, lambda, gatsby

como puedo interactuar con un Docker container en AWS?
Es decir, me gustaria poder desde una Lambda function decirle al docker container que haga algo.
Un ejemplo mas concreto, en ese docker container quiero tener un sitio hecho en Gatsby. La función que quiero realizar en un `gatsby build`, disparado desde mi Lambda function.
Sugerencias? documentacion ? Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Por definición, un contenedor docker no tiene estado, luego no puedes alterar su estado interno. Eso es en teoría, en la práctica sí es posible pero no es para lo que se diseñó docker.

Una opción podría ser almacenar los recursos que precisa el contenedor en S3. Entonces la lambda hace cambios en ese bucket y reconstruye el contenedor. Finalmente tendrías que recargar el contenedor de docker.

¿Cómo se hace esto último?

Bueno, si el contenedor está en kubernetes tendrías que publicar una nueva versión de la imagen docker en ECR y actualizar el despliegue de kubernetes. Si, en cambio, el contenedor se encuentra en una instancia de S3, tendrás que ejecutar algún script en dicha instancia para que se elimine el contenedor actual y se cree un nuevo contenedor a partir de la nueva imagen

Si insistes en modificar el estado de la imagen... necesitarás algún endpoint en el servidor que te permita hacer llegar ese tipo de órdenes al contenedor (y programar los scripts correspondientes en el servidor). El problema que tiene este enfoque es que esos endpoints quedan expuestos, de tal forma que un atacante que los encuentre podría utilizarlos con fines personales